# How to change colors of Vim editor?

Tags: colorscheme

I tried to change colors of Vim editor by going to the screen properties and change the color of background and text. It did not work.

I like to know how to change the colors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have mistaken your terminal color scheme with the Vim color theme. To change the Vim color theme, you need to use `:color` command, followed by a valid color theme on your system, for example,  `color desert`.

Comment: You can use `<tab>` completion with many commands, like `:colorscheme` to cycle through the given colorscheme options. Also can use `<c-d>` to list out the completions.  See `:h cmdline-completion` for more help

Comment: Might want to visit https://vimcolors.com